# Icon font and label text in separate lines

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a label title and an icon that I tried to center both vertically and horizontally using flex. The label is working fine; the only issue is with the icon.

I want the icon to be above the label title and not beside it. I tried used `<br>`, but it still doesn't work.

Code snippet below and [JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/jomnozee/):

```css
.radio input[type="radio"] + label {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #cccbc8;
  display: flex;
  height: 150px;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio-inline radio input_type">
  <input id="Best offers" name="54_answer" type="radio" next-question-id="" value="Best offers">
  <label for="Best offers">Best offers <br> <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i></label>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Is [this](http://i.imgur.com/UTiuoE4.png) what you get? Where do you it positioned?

Comment: same here the font-awesome icon is missing

Comment: try adding the icon in a span element see what that does

Comment: you must use http://fontawesome.io/ to be able the icon

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, so by using `display: flex` your elements will be displayed inline. There is an option for flex to specify if we want to display our elements in a row or in a column style (by default is row). In your case you want by column that's why add this to your class

```
flex-direction: column-reverse
```

This will put your icon above text.

Comment: "inline" really means something completely different than you are implying here - you are talking about horizontal alignment.

Answer (score 0):

The selector in your CSS rule is completely wrong, and `flex-direction` has to be `column`. Try as follows:

```css
.radio-inline.radio.input_type {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #cccbc8;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 150px;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
}
.radio-inline label {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio-inline radio input_type">
  <input id="Best offers" name="54_answer" type="radio" next-question-id="" value="Best offers">
  <label for="Best offers">Best offers <br> <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i></label>
</div>
```